# P-MOSFET driver

Tags: mosfet-driver, p-channel, drive

I need to drive a P-channel MOSFET from an output of a 74HC595 shift register which is controlled by an ESP32.

The MOSFET load will be a high power LED. Once the register is latched the outputs will stay fully ON or OFF for long periods of time.

I was thinking of implementing the circuit below since the power supply will always be 15V.
I simulated and it seems to work fine. Do you see any issues (since there is no gate limiting resistor?)

[image]

Comment: Your high-power LED is modeled as a resistor. LEDs aren't resistors, they aren't well regulated as a voltage controlled device. Are you using M1 to switch power to a current source, or what?

Comment: Yes M1 will act as an on/off switch.

Comment: It might be worth your while checking to see if you can find a different FET for M1 where the Vgs can withstand the full voltage. That would allow you to eliminate D1. The best part is no part.

Comment: Without D1, R1 will dissipate 15V/1k = 15mA, 0.3W when the LED is on.  If you don't need microsecond switching of M1, a higher value R1 could be used, up to 470k likely.

Comment: Off topic, but if you didn't mean to have those small circles shown, press `A` to toggle their visibility.

Comment: I dont think that i could spare D1. The Vgs of M1 is +- 12V. So I think to keep it above -12V.

Comment: would replacing the diode with another 1k resistor half the gate voltage?